# How to texture-paint individual pixels

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

**In 2.79** I can draw individual pixels by setting the brush size to 1px, like in this example (16x16px image):
[image]

**Starting from 2.80** the drawing produces extra pixels:
[image]

As you can see the antialiasing is disabled, I also tried to tweak all the other settings, but wasn't able to achieve 2.79 behavior.

Comment: I'd recommend submitting a bug report on this - there is no place I can find that allows to adjust something to turn it on or off, and this behavior is not correct.

Comment: @CraigDJones OK, thanks... created https://developer.blender.org/T81693

Comment: So this turned out to be a known bug for almost a year now :/
https://developer.blender.org/T71403

Comment: Does that give you a solution in turning the Falloff to 'Constant'?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me - did you try it?

Comment: Couldn't try til now - no, it solves only the problem of the semi transparent pixels, but still paints the extra pixels solid so you end up getting 2-3 pixels at a dab.

Comment: @CraigDJones OK, but I really need just 1 pixel drawing, like in 2.79. There is even a fix for that https://developer.blender.org/D6209, unfortunately developers didn't include it to the build, not sure why.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Do the same falloff as shown here]

**Starting from 2.80** to NOT produce extra pixels, you can change brush falloff graph in way shown on the gif above.

Make a sharp transition from brush center to it edges.

As you can see radius is setted to 1px, Anti-Aliasing is disabled, 4x4px texture size.